# Magento Admin/Backend is not showing properly after login

Tags: admin, error, importexport, admin-panel

[image: after login]

After Login into the admin panel, I have this screen, I am not sure how to fix this.

1. I have just moved from one hosting to other and added one Extension.
2. I am not able to see the extension so, wasn't available for remove
   the extension.

Comment: This might be `php` error, please go through Magento `exception.log` and `system.log` file under `Magento Root/var/log/` directory. Also check your server `error.log` file it helps you to address the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SSH or FTP to access your `app/etc/modules` directory and open the XML file of the last installed extension.

Search for the tag `<active>true</active>` and change it to `<active>false</active>`. Save the file.

Also clear your `/var/cache/` directory. Flush Redis and Vagrant if any of this is installed.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for this! This works. I can use my admin panel.